# JSF with facelets in Tomcat7

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, tomcat7

I am trying to deploy a  JSF 2.0 application with Facelets 1.1.14 to Tomcat7. I am getting the following exceptions:

```
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.0 (FCS b23) for context '/AdminUI'

3 Aug, 2011 7:44:32 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance

INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
3 Aug, 2011 7:44:33 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager initialized
INFO: Unsanitized stacktrace from failed start...
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:200)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:312)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:416)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:370)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:313)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:262)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:337)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
3 Aug, 2011 7:44:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
3 Aug, 2011 7:44:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/AdminUI] startup failed due to previous errors
3 Aug, 2011 7:44:33 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:804)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:306)
        at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:104)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4763)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$4.run(StandardContext.java:5472)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)    
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)    
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1363)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1391)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1401)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1380)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
3 Aug, 2011 7:44:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/AdminUI] appears to have started a thread named [Mojarra-ResourceCache-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Iam having the following jars under/WEB-INF/lib/

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
asm-3.1.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.final.jar
hibernate-core-3.6.5.final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.5.final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
javassist-3.12.0.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar
jsf-api-2.0.jar
jsf-impl-2.0.0.jar
jta-1.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSF 2.0 ships with Facelets 2.0 bundled. The Facelets 1.x JAR file would only collide with this. You should **remove** the Facelets 1.x JAR file.

All JAR files you need for developing JSF 2.0 with Facelets on Tomcat are `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar`.

Comment: I removed the facelets jar from my app, but still found the same error on deploy

Comment: Then your classpath is still polluted. What JARs do you now have in `/WEB-INF/lib`? Did you ever manipulate the JDK/JRE's and Tomcat's own libraries and/or classpath management? If so, undo that all. JDK/JRE and Tomcat7 should be kept in its default trim.

Comment: I edited my post by adding the jars in my lib. Is the configuration is correct? I never manipulate any classpath on tomcat, JDK/JRE.

Comment: I see that you're using old Mojarra 2.0.0. Please try to use the most recent one first, 2.1.2. You can get it all here: http://javaserverfaces.java.net/

Comment: @BalusC, where does mojarra jar go?

Comment: @Pere: only when you're using a non-JEE server such as Tomcat, then it has to ultimately end up in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the WAR, else you shouldn't provide it (as a normal JEE server already provides it out the box).