# JSF 2.0 project with eclipse and tomcat 7

Tags: java, jsf-2, classnotfoundexception

I am creating a new JSF 2.0 project and getting:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config

Exception. If I copy paste jstl-api 1.2 and jstl-impl-1.2 jar  WebContent\WEB-INF\lib some other exception

> at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:364)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:154)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)

is getting generated infinitely.
What is going wrong?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6926468/757071)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove `jstl api 1.2` and `jstl impl 1.2` and use `jstl 1.2`. By the way did you use `jsp api` jar? if your answer is yes, then the possible cause of the first exception is the conflict of it with the `jsp api` jar in the tomcat lib.  **Should Visit [the page of Mkyoung](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/) while starting JSF 2.0.** This will help you a lot!

Happy Coding!